# call child methods from parent of a component rendered using a map function in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

am building a form which insert fields depending on the json definition of the field the json object is parsed and passed on to a switch statement which select an appropriate widget and insert it into an array this array is sorted then rendered using array map 
what i need to achieve is to call a validate field of each field after a submit is pressed now how can i access this elements a call the appropriate validate logic

**what i have tried so far**

1. using refs when i push the widgets into the array 
   throw error relating to assigning refs outside render function

   2. wrap the call to map within a referenced view and access the widgets as children of that view via `this.refs["myWrapper].props.children`
      this approach give me access to my widgets but the objects returned doesn't contain my methods so calling them throw error for not a function

**code sample**

`export class myForm extends Component{

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.fields=[];
}

getFields(fields){

 let {formName,title}=this.props;

    let field,_fields=[],item;

    fields= this.sortFieldsOrder(fields);


    fields.forEach((sect,i)=>{
        for(field in sect)
        {
            item=sect[field];
            switch (item.widget){

                case "inlineText":
                    _fields.push(
                        <EbTextInput  key={field}

                                     {...{...item.props,formName,title}}
                                     field={field}
                                     label={item.hasOwnProperty("label")?item.label:""}
                                     validator={item.hasOwnProperty("validator")?item.validator:()=>{}}
                        />
                    );

                    break;
                case "hidden":

                    _fields.push(
                        <EbHiddenInput  key={field}
                                       {...{...item.props,formName,title}}
                                       field={field}
                                       label={item.hasOwnProperty("label")?item.label:""}
                                       validator={item.hasOwnProperty("validator")?item.validator:()=>{}}
                        />
                    );
                    break;
                case"modal":
                    _fields.push(

                        <EbModalInput
                                      key={field}
                                      {...{...item.props,formName,title}}
                                      field={field}
                                      fields={item.props.fields instanceof Array?this.getFields(item.props.fields):[]}
                                      label={item.hasOwnProperty("label")?item.label:""}
                                      validator={item.hasOwnProperty("validator")?item.validator:()=>{}}
                        />

                    );
                    break;
                case"filePicker":

                  let  picker=<EbFilePickerInput key={field}
                                                 {...{...item.props,formName,title}}
                                                 field={field}
                                                 label={item.hasOwnProperty("label")?item.label:""}
                                                 validator={item.hasOwnProperty("validator")?item.validator:()=>{}}
                  />;
                    picker=[picker];

                    _fields.push(
                        <EbModalInput  key={field}
                                      {...{...item.props,formName,title}}
                                      field={field}
                                      fields={picker}
                                      label={item.hasOwnProperty("label")?item.label:""}
                                      validator={item.hasOwnProperty("validator")?item.validator:()=>{}}
                        />
                    );
                    break;
                case "option":
                    _fields.push(
                        <EbOptionInput

                            key={field}
                            {...{...item.props,formName,title}}
                            field={field}
                            fields={item.props.fields instanceof Array?this.getFields(item.props.fields):[]}
                            label={item.hasOwnProperty("label")?item.label:""}
                            validator={item.hasOwnProperty("validator")?item.validator:()=>{}}                            />
                    );
                    break;
                default:

            }


        }
    });
    return _fields;
}
sortFieldsOrder(arr){
    return  arr.sort((a,b)=>{
        let keyA=Object.keys(a)[0];
        let keyB=Object.keys(b)[0];
        if(a[keyA]["order"]<b[keyB]["order"])return 1;
        if(a[keyA]["order"]>b[keyB]["order"])return -1;
        return 0;
    });
}
componentWillMount(){

    let {fields}=this.props;
    this.fields=this.getFields(fields)

}
renderFields(){
   return this.fields.map((item)=>{
        return item;
    })
}
validateForm(){
    let field;
    let fields=this.refs["wrapper"].props.children;
    let status=true;
    React.Children.map(this.refs["wrapper"].props.children, (child) => {
        if(!child.validate()){
            status= false;
            console.log("valid form cheki");
            // break;
        }
    })



   return status;
}
render(){
    return(
        <View ref="wrapper" style={[styles.flex1]}>
            {this.renderFields()}
            <Button text="Submit" onPress={(e)=>{
                if(this.validateForm()){
                    //alert("valid form")
                }
                else
                    alert("invalid form")
            }}> </Button>
        </View>)
}
```

}

`

Comment: Parents don't call child methods. Parents pass their children props. If the parent wants to signal a change down the component hierarchy, it passes its child(ren) a new set of props.

Comment: so you suggest i pass some sort of props maybe using redux to trigger the validation logic. that would be easy and seams more legit thanks for your comment i will simply let the question stay little longer to see if there is a defferent view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react it is ant pattern to access nodes directly for whatever reason so i decided to follow on the first comment from above using redux I can send down a validation signal and let each widget validate its own state this reduce coupling and simple to implement and debug so I would recommend everyone with same question to follow this pass

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use refs in your case, but instead of generating children components by calling `getFields` in `componentWillMount`, you'd better call it directly in `render` method. In other words, there's no need to have a `this.fields`, you can render them directly. As long as you have correct keys, React will manage the cache properly.

Comment: I wanted to avoid iterating on fields on each render thats why this.fields in componentsWillMount

Comment: Iterating on fields is actually cheap compared to rendering, although you cached the components, if it's re-rendered, the cost won't be very different no matter you re-iterate fields or not, unless you have tons of fields, for example more than 1000.

Comment: Secondly, since your component seems stateless, it won't get re-rendered too often, then the iteration won't happen frequently. In a nutshell, I suggest putting all components generation part into the render flow instead of caching the components. Some mechanism, the ref binding for example, depends on it.

Comment: Yes it's cheap to iterate on few fields but it will require iterating three times first sorting, second getting fields third on form validation and in the modal widget it follow the same pattern so it will have its own child widgets which will need sorting and getting fields that what makes me decide to do all this once in before mounting and just in case I go rogue and  put hundreds of fields

Comment: You can still cache the sort result if necessary, I mean do not cache components, cache data structure instead.

Comment: Yah I think that should do